# sql PDO fetchall duplicate object keys?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've issue in `PDO` using `fetchAll()` method .

when execute the results showing array of objects its fine , but each object has duplicate keys for example :

```
$catid = intval( $api->param['catid'] );

      $json   = array();
      $prepar = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cat_sub WHERE `catid` = :catid ORDER BY `orderid` asc";

      try{

               $q = $api->pdo->prepare($prepar);

               $q->bindparam(":catid" , $catid , PDO::PARAM_INT);

               $q->execute();

               $json = $q->fetchAll();

      }catch( PDOException $e ){

           $api->showError = $e->getMessage();

      }

      echo json_encode($json);
      exit();
```

the output of each object is

```
{
"subcatid":"6",
"0":"6",
"title":"coool ",
"1":"coool ",
"catid":"2",
"2":"2",
"orderid":"1",
"3":"1"
},
```

and its should be

```
{
"subcatid":"6",
"title":"coool ",
"catid":"2",
"orderid":"1",
},
```

any advice how to do this without loop or foreach :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to specify [fetching mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 8):

Please specify the Mode of fetching

Change

```
$json = $q->fetchAll();
```

to

```
$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: what is difference between your answer & @Justinas ?

Comment: @RamSharma mine is with link to Documentation wit all fetching modes available.

Comment: I just specified the error. Thats all. :) But @Justinas had posted it before me . :)

Comment: I feel both the answers are same, instead repeating same answer better you should like or up vote the answer of @Justinas

Comment: Actually I didn't see it while I am answering :)